# How to export a function in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to execute a function in another component. For that I am exporting that function. But I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: E:\PRACTICE\Reactjs\tutorial\01-starting-setup\src\Form.js: Export 'addTask' is not defined. (101:9)

99 | }
100 |
> 101 | export { addTask };
|                ^
102 | export default Form;
103 |
at parser.next (<anonymous>)
```

This is my code:

```
const Form = () => {

 const [task, setTask] = useState('');
.....

    function addTask (event) {


    }
    
    return (
       ....
        )
    }
export { addTask };
export default Form;
```

Comment: just use `export const addTask = event => {`

Comment: It is giving this SyntaxError `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level.`

Comment: yes you need to add this method outside Form body. check Girgetto's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addTask()` is undefined because it's defined inside `Form` component, you can move it outside to change the scope:

```
function addTask (event) {
...
}
const Form = () => {

 const [task, setTask] = useState('');
.....
    
    return (
       ....
        )
    }
export { addTask };
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [task, setTask] = useState('');
.....

   export const addTask (event) {

 //...code 
    }
    
    return (
       ....
        )
    }
export default Form;
```

Comment: It is also showing the same Syntaxerror `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level.`

Comment: Please, describe your code: what is going on here and how it resolves the issue. It will allow future readers to follow the logic and apply it to similar questions to resolve them by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I want to deploy the front-end(react js) and back-end(asp.net) on iis server,

and I want to use the base URL(eg. http://localhost:3000) on all my react js pages/modules. so, i create a page `BaseUrl.js` and export on all the pages

```
export let checkWindowName = window.location.origin
```

and export on all the pages

```
import {checkWindowName} from "../../BaseUrl"
```

like this

also if you want to export the function like below(ES6 named export)

```
function collection() {
let data = {};
function getData(key) {
    return data[key];
}
function setData(key, value) {
    data[key] = value;
}
return {
    getData: getData,
    setData: setData
};
}

const instanceOfCollection = collection()
export default instanceOfCollection
```

then

```
import { setter, getter } from 'my_module'
```

or

```
import * as myCollection from 'my_module'
myCollection.getter()
myCollection.setter()
```